# Change data object input type to an array of matching types

Tags: typescript

Edit: Updated function so it works, just `Data` type is wrong, because that's the problem I am trying to solve.

My function takes a data object, containing simple key-value pairs.
That are in turn added to a storage with the same key names, just added to an array.

```
const storage: Record<string, unknown[]> = {}

function test<Data extends Record<string, unknown>>(data: Data, callback: (data: Data) => any) {
    // Add data
    Object.entries(data).forEach(([ key, value ]) => {
        storage[key]?.push(value);
    });
    
    // timeout logic...
    
    // callback
    return callback(storage);
}

test({
    name: 'john',
    age: 3,
}, (data) => {
    // data should be {name: string[], age: number[]}
})
```

How can I tell the callback that the type of data sent back is in an array.

Data passed in is somehting like

```
{name: string, age: number, gender: 'm' | 'f'}
```

and the data I want to send back should be the type like this

```
{name: string[], age: number[], gender: ('m' | 'f')[]}
```

Appreciate the help.
Thanks.

Comment: Please [edit] the code so it's a [mre] where the only issues present are the ones you're asking about. `storage` is not defined and `typeof Data` is not valid.  Please test your code in a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) and then paste a reproducible version here as plaintext.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use mapping type:

```
const storage: Record<string, unknown[]> = {}

function test<Key extends string, Value extends unknown,
    Data extends Record<Key, Value>>
    (data: Data, callback: (data: { [Key in string]: unknown[] }) => any) {
    // Add data
    Object.entries(data).forEach(([ key, value ]) => {
        storage[key]?.push(value);
    });
    
    // timeout logic...
    
    // callback
    return callback(storage);
}

test({
    name: 'john',
    age: 3,
}, (data) => {
    // data should be {name: string[], age: number[]}
})
```